# How to 'like' a public facebook post using php

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have access token of some user with publish_actions permission.
and i can successfully post on user wall with php.

But when I tried to 'like' someone public post using facebook php sdk with below code:

```
$token='someone access token' ;

$postid='some post id which i need to like';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(['app_id' => APPID, 'app_secret' => APPSECRET ,'default_graph_version'=> VERSION, ]);

$response=$fb->post('/'.$postid.'/likes', [], $token);
```

I got the error .. 
"Graph returned an error: (#12) singular links API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher"

Can some one help me Please... Thanks

Comment: i am not sure if that is even possible with the api, but what for do you need it anyway? what is the exact use case?

Comment: I read documentation here [link] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes [link]

And i want to like any public post or my fb friends's post via above mention api.

Might be i did not understand it.

Comment: i know, but WHY? why not just do this on facebook.com instead?

Comment: Actually we want to like/promote a post in bulks. so that all the user we already have access token with publish_action permission , can like a post in bulk and instantly.
is this possible?

Comment: so...autoliking? and you don´t see any problem with this? it does not matter if it´s possible or not, it´s clearly not allowed. and obviously you would not get publish_actions approved in the login review, even if it would be possible.

Comment: Did you solve this?